# How many system calls are there in linux kernel 2.6?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

How many system calls are there totally in linux 2.6 kernel. Does the number of system calls vary from version to version.

Comment: Easily discoverable from the source.

Comment: [here](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the 3.0 (which is not different from 2.6 from that point of view), the file `syscall_table.S` contains 326 entries.

It is located in `arch/m32r/kernel/syscall_table.S`.

Answer (score 2):

The number varies from version, including minor versions, so there isn't a good hard number to answer to your question. Check this out: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html

Answer (score 2):

It varies slightly between architectures. Some architectures have syscalls which are either architecture-specific, or provide different sizes of parameters to the same routine.

Look at the system call table in the version and architecture you're interested in (Aif answered for the "m32r" architecture)

Comment: I am intrested in x86 architecture, For x86 architecure arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S it contains 347 system_calls in the Linux 3.0-rc4 release. The sha-id for the git repo is 56299378726d5f2ba8d3c8cbbd13cb280ba45e4f.